# REST API: advice on using separate endpoint or adding a RequestParam

Tags: java, rest, api

We have a java web application developed in Spring whit a REST api that models a simple messageboard and currently I'm facing a problem.

I have several endpoints that return the several json representations of my onjects.
Es:

```
project/api/sections
project/api/discussions
project/api/posts
```

I also have a `BaseController` that serves the basic CRUD operations; all my other controllers extend this `BaseController`

Then I added some filters for searching discussions and I added an endpoint `discussions/search`; the endpoints accepts several optional parameters in the form of `RequestParams`, this is the controller method signature:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/search",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Discussions> findDiscussioniForumEPT(@RequestParam (value = "idSection", required=false) String idSection,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="competenzeArray", required=false) String[] parametersArray,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="flUnreadDiscussions", required=false) boolean flUnreadDiscussions,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="flIncludeArchivedDiscussions", required=false) boolean flIncludeArchivedDiscussions)
```

The last boolean parameter works by filtering or not filtering the discussions based on a date property of the discussion object (archived discussions)
.

Now another feature has to be added, the functionality to **search ONLY the archived discussions**.

I thought about adding another endpoint in the form of

```
project/api/discussions/archived
```

but this would force me to add on this other method almost all the parameters already there on the other endpoint `project/api/discussions/search`

On the other hand I could add another parameter on the search endpoint to cover this case, adding complexity to the filter.

Is there a better design approach?

Answer (score 1):

Pure IMHO:
In general there are two separate aspects of the answer:

**1.**  Semantics:
As long as functionality is still “search”, but “archived only” for the new case, semantically it makes more sense to use “archived only” as another parameter (e.g. boolean true/false)

**2.**  Existing application architecture:

**a.**  If you have solid monolith application and has no intention to run separated set of (micro)service apps for each different endpoint (or subset of them),

then add another parameter rather than another endpoint makes more sense  semantically and from UI code prospective. As long as all other cases have same endpoint I guess it is easier to manage it, rather than add more endpoints to handle there.

**b.** But if different functionalities will run as separate (micro)services then new endpoint is preferable.

Let say:

there is one service app runs for “regular search” functionality, 
when another service app runs for “archived only search” functionality.

In this case you have to have different endpoints, just because you do not need to do anything to route request to the proper endpoint. It happens on network level.

But, route request based on request parameter requires additional layer which must decide where to pass request.

Something like that…

PS. But such kind of question here, can open a long discussion (based on everyone opinion), while it is not a purpose of this site as I know…

Comment: Thank you for your time @Vadim. My question is just for avoiding code duplication vs having a more restful approach; I'm still learning about REST so I have many doubts.
Anyway, we don't currently have any microservices achitecture, and just one monolithic backend

Comment: you are welcome - So, do not worry and use a parameter. it makes more sense and less code duplication... When (and if) you decide to go with microservices you will need to revisit and restructure everything anyway...  PS. ... I'm not a REST fan of any kind ... :-)